# Strange behavior binding WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm having trouble binding to the text property of a combobox. It seems like it doesn't bind until I select something in the combobox. Then it works fine.

Here is the code straight from a test app:

View

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
          Text="{Binding Test}" />
```

ViewModel

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListItems { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ListItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ListItems.Add("Southwest");
        ListItems.Add("South");
    }

    public string Test
    {
        get { return "South"; }
        set { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Test")); }
    }
}
```

However, when I reverse the order of the observable collection items, everything works fine.

```
ListItems.Add("South");
ListItems.Add("Southwest");
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I think that you should use SelectedItem property instead of Text

Comment: It's supposed to work with either. Like I showed, if you reverse the order of the strings in the collection, it works. I just don't understand why.

Comment: Like hameleon86 said, you shouldn't be binding to Text.  When binding on a control like a ComboBox (or ListBox, ListView, etc) you should only be binding to SelectedItem or SelectedValue to be modifying what is selected.

Comment: I stand corrected, I assumed the WPF combobox worked like the windows.forms combobox, which allows this type of behaviour. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx . It's just strange that I've never seen this before. I have a dozen comboboxes that are bound like this and they all work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text property doesn't work like this.
Read this document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text.aspx

Like suggested by hameleon86 use the selecteditem instead.

I think it Works if you reverse the order of your collection maybe because the Text property take the first item of the collection by default

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to do :

PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListItems"));

After you inserted the element.

Comment: I'll try it. I think that's what the ObservableCollection is supposed to do though.

Comment: No change, any other ideas?

Comment: I don't see why I need to create a new collection?

Comment: This comment for CeD's answer:)

Comment: @hameleon86 to raise this event was for the UI side to force refresh.